# Firebase screen view analytics of individual or particular user

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

In firebase console analytics, we can see the screen views report in events.
But this report is more of generic.
I would like to see the report of a individual user.

These are the details I would like to see in screen view analytics.

A individual user,

- screen name he viewed.
- How much time he spent on the particular screen.

Is it possible? Please help.

Comment: Yes, first you need to link your Firebase Analytics to [BigQuery](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/#integrations_with_other_services) or a similar data service.  From there you will be able to import your Data Tables into [Google Data Studio](https://datastudio.google.com).  You should be able to add a filter to constrain the Reports by `event.user_id`

Comment: Hi, @JamesPoag Thanks for your response. I tried to integrate with BigQuery. But in fcm, "Blaze plan is required for linking." is there. Which means I have to purchase the Blaze Plan. Can I connect with my free basic plan?

Comment: Sorry,  I don't think there's a way around that.  Firebase aggregates your analytics data and only holds the raw data for a very short period.